# Table of Contents point to first page when using external tex files

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex

Could someone explain why the TOC doesn't point to the right chapters/sections but instead always to the first page ?

**Main Tex files:**

```
% ... Preamble

% ========================= BEGIN DOCUMENT


\begin{document}



% ================ DOCUMENT HEAD


\frontmatter



    %FRONT PAGE
        \input{head/frontPage.tex}

    %DEDICATION (the initial quote)

        \input{head/dedication.tex}

    %ABSTRACT

        % \input{head/abstract}

    %INDEXES

        %summary and change name from Contents to Indice
        \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Indice}
        \tableofcontents



% ================ DOCUMENT BODY



\mainmatter


        \input{body/Introduction.tex}    
        \input{body/Test.tex}


% ....
```

Comment: Can you provide your preamble? Also, what is contained within the `\input` files? It would help us identify the source of the problem if we can replicate it... so how do we go about doing that? Supply us with something that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're currently experiencing.

Comment: I suspect some counter reset, thereby screwing up the hyper anchors